# Samsung M2070 losing connection to Ubuntu (20.04)

Tags: networking, drivers, printing, samsung

I'm having a strange problem with my Samsung Laser printer M2070 connected over WiFi to my Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

It's been installed using the Samsung Unified Driver (first the USB, then the driver, then the Settings/Printer adding) and works when first installed.

Then, after some minutes, if I try to print, it will say "Connecting to Printer", "Unable to Connect". Then, it will keep trying to connect and ultimately, after a few minutes, start printing.

The printer however was not in any kind of stand by mode. I can, at all times, access the printer using its IP address 192.168.0.18.

Could this be to the fact that 20.04 would require new drivers not yet issued? Why am I losing the connection to the printer and then regaining it. It's really frustrating.

Could this be solved by assigning somehow a static IP address?

```
gaj@gaj-Inspiron-3480-AIO:~$ lpstat -v
device for M2070: dnssd://Samsung%20M2070%20Series%20(SEC8425197991A6)._printer._tcp.local/
device for Samsung_M2070_Series_SEC8425197991A6_: implicitclass://Samsung_M2070_Series_SEC8425197991A6_/

gaj@gaj-Inspiron-3480-AIO:~$ lpstat -a
M2070 accepting requests since Sun 26 Apr 2020 14:53:41 CEST
Samsung_M2070_Series_SEC8425197991A6_ accepting requests since Sun 26 Apr 2020 14:31:07 CEST
```

Comment: Unfortunately I've had problems too. SANE driver installs but simple-scan fails to find the printer. Down grade to 16.04 works. Seems Samsung got out of printers and HP maintains the Samsung ULD drivers now.

Answer (score 0):

I have done the exact installment procedure but this time, when adding printer after installing its drivers through install.sh, I specified the HP destination to the IP address of the printer (HP 192.128.0.18) and it seems to be working fine, not losing connection.